# A question about the standard euclidean group $\mathbb{SE}(3)$

Tags: group-theory, rigid-transformation

I have a little perplexity about the following fact:

If we consider the *standard euclidean group* $\mathbb{SE}(3)$, an element $g$ can be represented by a matrix

$$\mathbb{SE}(n) \ni g=\begin{pmatrix}R & v \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \, \, , \, \, R \in \mathbb{SO}(3) \, , \, v \in \mathbb{R}^3.$$

So $g$ can be thought as a *mapping* $g : \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ *parametrized* by $R,v$.

What I don't understand is, isn't the $\mathbb{SE}(3)$ group originally used to describe a rotation + translation in a $3$-dimensional space? Or should we use $\mathbb{SE}(2)$ to describe such transformations in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional last row is only to write it conveniently as a matrix group. Then we can also take the vector $w\in \Bbb R^3$ with one component more and have the action on $\Bbb R^4$ as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} R & v \cr
 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} w \cr 1 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} Rw+v \cr 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
But of course we can still view this just as the action on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: but then we could translate+rotate a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ using an element of $\mathbb{SE}(2)$? Also why do we need the last row $0 , 1$ 'to write it conveniently as a matrix group' ?

Comment: Because it is an affine transofrmation $x\mapsto Rx+v$, which is not a linear transformation. To make it "linear" we need to embedd it one dimension higher.

Comment: Many many thanks, I got the point